# While Loop Weirdness in Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I noticed that java (hence probably C) has no problem with this:

```
while(condition1) {
    //do somethin'
} while(condition2);
```

Is this the same as:

```
while(condition1 && condition2) {
    //do somethin'
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, you have two loops.

```
while(condition1) {
  // do something
}

while(condition2); // second loop which does nothing.
```

The second loop is the same as

```
while(condition2) { }
```

EDIT: My suggestion is to use the automatic formatter in your IDE regularly. Otherwise you can create formatting which suggests the code does things it doesn't.

**example 1**

```
if (condition)
    statement1;
    statement2;
statement3;
```

In this example, it appears that the first two statements are part of the if condition, but only the first is.

**example 2**

```
http://www.google.com/
statement;
```

Doesn't look like legal Java, but it is, not for the reasons the formatting suggests ;)

Comment: @delmet, mark it answered if you are happy with this answer? :-)

Answer (score 4):

No, they are different.

The first `while(condition1)` will run first.

Then comes `while(condition2)`, which has nothing after it except a single `;` which means it's just some empty statement.

Remember that in control blocks like `if`, `for`, `while`, if you don't use the `{}` braces, then only the first immediate statement after it will be considered part of it.

Example:

```
if (condition)
    System.out.println("hello"); // prints only if condition is true.
    System.out.println("no"); // not bound to the 'if'. Prints regardless.

while (condition)
    ; // do nothing!
    System.out.println("something"); // not bound to the while
```

**Edit The empty while loop is mentioned in the [Java code conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc6.html)**

> 7.6    `while` Statements
>
> A `while` statement should have the following form:

```
while (condition) {
    statements;
}
```

> An empty while statement should have the following form:

```
while (condition);
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no construct is java as shown in the first form. You have probably seen

```
do {

} while (cond)
```

**EDIT** : You are misreading the first form. There should have been a line break after the `}`. This confused me as well.